# How can I evaluate $\int _0^1\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(3\sqrt{\frac{a}{4-a}}\right)}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{4-a}}\:\mathrm{d}a$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have the integral:
$$\int _0^1\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(3\sqrt{\frac{a}{4-a}}\right)}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{4-a}}\:\mathrm{d}a.$$
If I use $u=3\sqrt{\frac{a}{4-a}}$, I get
$$6\int _0^{\sqrt{3}}\:\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(u\right)}{u^2+9}\mathrm{d}u$$
But I cant get past this. I tried integration by parts but nothing seems to come out from that.

Comment: It seems possible you'll only be able to approximate it. At least, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D+sqrt%283%29+of+arctan%28x%29%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+9%29) only offers an approximation of your second integral. (Granted that doesn't mean it's impossible...)

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: it comes from calculating another integral that my friend gave me

Comment: @Ty. No, it has a closed form expression which is $$\frac{\pi ^2}{18}-\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(-3\right)}{4}-\frac{\ln \left(2\right)\ln \left(3\right)}{2}$$ it seems it agrees with wolfram alpha as well i just have no idea how to obtain it.

Comment: I would write $\arctan(u)=\int_0^1\frac{u}{1+u^2 x^2}dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $$ \tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{i}{2} \, \ln\left( \frac{1 - i \, x}{1 + i \, x} \right) $$ then
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x^2 + a^2} \, dx &= \frac{i}{2} \, \left( \int \frac{\ln(1 - i \, x)}{x^2 + a^2} \, dx - \int \frac{\ln(1 + i \, x)}{x^2 + a^2} \, dx \right).
\end{align}
Using
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\ln(1 + i \, x)}{x^2 + a^2} \, dx &= \frac{i}{2 \, a} \, \left[ - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1+ i \, x}{1 - a}\right) + \text{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{1 + i \, x}{1 + a}\right) + \ln(1 + i \, x) \, \ln\left( \frac{a-1}{a+1} \cdot \frac{a - i \, x}{a + i \, x}\right)  \right] \\
\int \frac{\ln(1 - i \, x)}{x^2 + a^2} \, dx 
&= \frac{i}{2 \, a} \, \left[ - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1- i \, x}{1 + a}\right) + \text{Li}_{2}\left( \frac{1 - i \, x}{1 - a}\right) + \ln(1 - i \, x) \, \ln\left( \frac{a+1}{a-1} \cdot \frac{a - i \, x}{a + i \, x}\right)  \right]
\end{align}
then the result can be found in closed form with:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x^2 + a^2} \, dx &= \frac{-1}{4 \, a} \, \left[ - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1- i \, x}{1 + a}\right) - \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1 + i \, x}{1 + a}\right) + \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1 - i \, x}{1 - a}\right) + \text{Li}_{2}\left(\frac{1 + i \, x}{1 - a}\right) \\+ \ln(1 + x^2) \, \ln\left(\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right) - 4 \, \tan^{-1}(x) \, \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) \right]
\end{align}

The integral with the desired limits is:
$$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x^2 + 3^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{6} \, \left( \frac{\zeta(2)}{3} - \frac{\ln(2) \, \ln(3)}{2} - \frac{\text{Li}_{2}(-3)}{4} \right). $$

Also:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \tan^{-1}\left( 3 \, \sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}} \right) \, \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x \, (4-x)}} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{3} - \frac{\ln(2) \, \ln(3)}{2} - \frac{\text{Li}_{2}(-3)}{4}. $$

Comment: No need to calculate the two integrals as we know that $\arctan(x)=\Im\{\ln(1+ix)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the antiderivative, we could combine two things
$$ \frac 6 {u^2+9}=\frac{i}{u+3 i}-\frac{i}{u-3 i}$$
$$\tan^{-1}(u) = \frac{i}{2} \, \log(1-iu)-\frac{i}{2} \, \log(1+iu) $$ and make
$$I=6\int\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(u\right)}{u^2+9}\,du=$$
$$\frac 12 \left( \frac{\log (1-i u)}{u-3 i}-\frac{\log (1-i u)}{u+3 i}-\frac{\log (1+i u)}{u-3
   i}+\frac{\log (1+i u)}{u+3 i}\right)$$ and recall that
$$\int \frac{\log (1+i u)}{u+i b}\,du=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i u}{1+b}\right)+\log (1+i u) \log \left(\frac{b-iu}{1+b}\right)$$
$$\int \frac{\log (1-i u)}{u+i b}\,du=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-i u}{1-b}\right)+\log (1-i u) \log \left(\frac{-b+i   u}{1-b}\right)$$ and the definite integral is
$$\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-\frac{\log ^2(2)}{2}+\frac 12 \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(1-i
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(1+i
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \right)$$ which, once simplified, gives the result already provided in comments and answers.